# Ubuntu trouble with USB ports

Tags: usb, 13.04

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 (not, I'm new to Linux in general, but I've also tried to install 12.10 back before 13.04), and the USB ports aren't working. I had this problem in 12.10 as well. All of them (even the front two USB 3.0 ports on the front of my case) except the two USB 3.0 on my mobo (GA-990FXA-UD3) do not work.

Is there a way to fix this in Ubuntu, or is it a problem with my hardware?

CPU is an FX-8350 in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems on my pc I had 2.0 ports and 3.0 ports all the 2.0 ports work perfectly, I am able to receive power from my 3.0 ports, this problem persisted back when I ad windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.04, I haven't had much luck in getting it to work.

One tip I came across is that it needs to be activated in BIOS, I tried that with my ASUS P8-z68 V MOBO. but I am still having issues, I think I may have to update bios, I recommend you try and look in BIOs under Advanced and see if there is an option for usb 3.0.

Sorry I cant be of any more help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no fix for you but I am having the same issue with 13.04 on my Acer Predator - even though it works fine off the LiveCD.